# Eagle V6 and CNC router

Tags: pcb-fabrication, eaglecad, cnc

Any one used Eagle V6 and CNC router to produce prototype PCB boards. I have a high res CNC router HighZ1000-s/T which accepts G-code and HPGL. I am pretty sure that at the end of the day it will well work. Just looking for bit of advice from anyone who has already done it and can tell me what not to do and must do.

Answer (score 4):

[PCB-GCODE](http://www.pcbgcode.org/) ([alternative site](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/pcb-gcode/)) is a free program that let's you convert from EAGLE's .brd file to [G-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code) file.

These are the steps to follow (from [this site](http://www.pcbgcode.com/)):

> 1. Enter the electrical schematic in EAGLE.
> 2. Layout the PCB artwork in EAGLE.
> 3. Run the PCB-GCODE.ULP program (from within EAGLE layout) to
>      generate the G-code text files needed by the CNC machine.
> 4. Use a G-code editor/plotter/viewer to verify and optimize the G-code
>      files.
> 5. Setup the CNC machine and mill the PCB isolation outlines using the
>      verified G-code file.

Comment: Cheers mate, I will give it a go.

Comment: @ZulfqarAli Other useful link: http://www.brusselsprout.org/PCB-Routing/